# How to swap 2 Divs in a Container with Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I achieve something like this.

I have a Container with

```
<div class="div1">1</div>
<div class="div2">2</div>
<div class="div3">3</div>
<div class="div4">4</div>
<div class="div5">5</div>
```

What I now want to archieve for example: If I have
const div1ToSwap = ( div 1 )
const div2ToSwap = ( div 4 )

That the final result will be

```
<div class="div4">4</div>
<div class="div2">2</div>
<div class="div3">3</div>
<div class="div1">1</div>
<div class="div5">5</div>
```

Comment: `parentElement.removeChild(childElement)` removes an element from the DOM. You can use that to move them into an array (ideally in the desired order already). Then .append() them back to the parent.

Comment: Is this purely for display purposes? Or do you wish to do more with the elements in order?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very hacky way to do it, but this way you don't need to remove all elements then append them back in.

```js
let div1 = document.querySelector(".div1");
let div4 = document.querySelector(".div4");
let temp = div1.cloneNode(true);

div1.innerHTML = div4.innerHTML;
div1.className = div4.className;

div4.innerHTML = temp.innerHTML;
div4.className = temp.className;
```

```html
<div class="div1">1</div>
<div class="div2">2</div>
<div class="div3">3</div>
<div class="div4">4</div>
<div class="div5">5</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's simple, first you need to container all the div you need to make this script like this, we will write the function later
you can try it by the link https://codepen.io/nt0412/pen/rNJWMKP

```
<div class="all-div-container">
   <div class="div1" onclick="swapDiv(event,this);">
         1
   </div>
   <div class="div2" onclick="swapDiv(event,this);">
         2
   </div>
   <div class="div3" onclick="swapDiv(event,this);">
         3
   </div>
   <div class="div4" onclick="swapDiv(event,this);">
         4
   </div>
   <div class="div5" onclick="swapDiv(event,this);">
         5
   </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function swapDiv(event, elem) {
        elem.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, elem.parentNode.firstChild);
    }
</script>
```